# How can I prove that this graph and $K_{3,3}$ are isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory

If we have a simple graph with $6$ vertices, that does not have any three-vertex cycles and has $3$ edges going out of each vertex. How can I prove that this graph and $K_{3,3}$ are isomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We claim that this graph $G$ has no $5$-cycles. To prove, suppose for a contradiction that such graph has a $5$-cycle.

[image]

Then, in the above graph, in order for vertex $1$ to have degree $3$, it must be adjacent to vertex $6$ since if it is adjacent to any other vertex, we would have a triangle. Similarly, vertex $5$ must be adjacent to vertex $6$ too. But then we have a $3$-cycle $(156)$, a contradiction. Thus, $G$ has no $3$-cycles and no $5$-cycles. But this mean $G$ cannot have an odd cycle, therefore is bipartite. Can you complete the argument now?

Answer (score 2):

Pick some vertex $v$ and consider its open neighborhood $N(v)=\{a,b,c\}$. Note that none of $a,b,c$ can be adjacent to another, since otherwise we would have a triangle. So each of them have the open neighborhood $\{u,v,w\}$, where $u,w$ are the remaining two vertices. This shows that the graph is 3-regular bipartite on 6 vertices with partitions of size 3, hence the $K_{3,3}$.